# How to create a program that manipulates excel data to sort ids into categories?

Tags: python, excel, vba, sorting

I'm looking to create a python program using a combination of **Python, Excel, VBA, Pandas, and an Excel-Python module like xlwings** that will:

-Read an excel table with each row representing a user id and the following columns for each user id representing a time

-Sort user ids into groups based on the times in their rows. Each group will have a max amount of users, and if the group is full, the next time in the given user's row would be considered. (i.e. for User 1, the following times are listed: B1 - 9AM, C1 - 10:30AM, D1 - 11AM. Try to sort User 1 into the 9AM group, unless 9AM group is full, in which case try to sort into the 10:30AM group, etc.)

-Iterate this formula for thousands of ids and hundreds of groups

-Spit the data back into an excel sheet with each column being a group and below it the list of users that have been allocated to each group

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why the python and mysql tags?

Comment: because I am writing a program in python, and it could involve turning the excel into a csv to use w/python and sql

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a stronger general purpose programming language to use instead of VBA, I might suggest using the Microsoft Office .NET interop library. I believe it is an optional install with Microsoft Office. You can then use any .NET language (including Python http://ironpython.net) to look into the file, pull the data you need, and then dump it back in.

You will need to be careful as achieving optimal performance is not easy.

You will also need to be careful with how the interop library works with Excel instances. It actually opens a background instance of Excel which may not play well with open instances. I've had to write a lot of code to kill the instances of Excel at program completion otherwise things crash and hang all over.

Here's some sample code in C#. You can replace with Python as you see fit. You can have C# and Python projects together in the same solution in Visual studio and reference back and forth.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
int excelHWnd = 0;

public static void KillProcessWithThisWindow(int hWnd)
{
    uint processID = 0;
    IntPtr window = new IntPtr(hWnd);
    uint threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, out  processID);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)processID);
    p.Kill();
}

private void OpenExcel()
{
    if (excel!=null)
        try { KillProcessWithThisWindow(excelHWnd); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace); }
    excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excel.ScreenUpdating = false;
    excel.DisplayStatusBar = false;
    excel.EnableEvents = false;
    excelHWnd = excel.Hwnd;
}

private void Cleanup()
{
    try { excel.Quit(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace); }
    try { KillProcessWithThisWindow(excelHWnd); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace); }
    excel = null;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response! However, due to my limited programming knowledge, I was hoping to use a combination of Python, VBA, Pandas, and Xlwings or another Python-excel package

Comment: It sounds like you already know what to use; It might be helpful to update the question to include your requirements and what you've tried that hasn't worked yet